# How to update based on anoter row in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, correlated-subquery

I want to create a query that updates an int based on the int of the row with an id that is 1 higher.

I have tried this query, but it says that i can't label the table in an update statement. But how do i reference it in my subquery?

```
update t1 a set `int1` = (select `int1` from t1 b where b.id=a.id+1);
```

How can I overcome that I can't use an alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
UPDATE
  t1 a
  JOIN t1 b
    ON b.id = a.id + 1
SET
  a.int1 = b.int1;
```

If there are holes in `id` values, the query may be changed.

Comment: It works, but like he said, the ON clause should be: ON b.id = a.id + 1

Comment: Oh, yes. I have changed the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, why does my example not work? Can anyone explain that?

Comment: From the reference - 'Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.' I think this may explain this behavior. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html